# Enum.GetValues() on Enum Type that is nested in unconstructed Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, enums, nested

Seems that standard methods for Enum member values retrieval can't work in case when soure Enum Type is nested inside unconstructed generic type:
        it throws exception "can't make array of open types".

I tried to find solution for this problem here on stackoverflow :: but, it seems no one wrote yet about this - therefore I'm sharing my solution I discovered after some painfull time wasted.

Methods that will fail:

- Enum.GetValues()
- Type.GetEnumValues()
- FieldInfo.GetValue(Type enumType) ::
  will fail too, so don't waste your time on something like this:

  MemberInfo[] enumMembers = input.GetMembers().Where(x => (x.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)).ToArray();

Root of the problem is: nested enumeration type inherits "unconstructed type" feature of the parent Type. Now it sounds obvious for me - but you might fall on same confusion like I was.

The solution is to construct a Type from the enumeration Type.

```
if (input.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
{
var genericInput = input.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(imbProjectResource) });
input = genericInput;
}
```

So, to make sure your code will work in all cases - insert this before input.GetValues() call.

I hope this helped someone since I was desperate for a post like this.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this is not a proper format for this website - a question should be a question and that is all. However it is perfectly OK for you to ask the question and then answer the question yourself (posting twice).

Comment: This is my first time posting something here. I'll follow the format for future activities. Thanks!

Comment: @user2087794 Please, go ahead and extract the solution part of your post into an answer. You can do that by editing the question.

Comment: Show us code where your initial calls are failing. "can't make array of open types" - when?